# How to access a website hosted on a laptop's localhost

Tags: ethernet, web-server, ubuntu

i have connected my raspberry pi B+ to my laptop via an ethernet cable. i am on an ubuntu machine and i have shared my internet connection through the network configuration of the laptop. so wifi-> laptop-> ethernet_cable->RPI. the connection is successfull and i can `sudo apt-get upgrade`  etc... on the raspberry pi.

Now, i am developing a flask application and i run it on my laptop's localhost `127.0.0.1:5000` **(i do not want to run the server on the RPI, that is not the rpi's purpose for the project)**. what should i `ping` on the raspberry pi in order to visit the website, make an api call etc.

If the information i provided is insufficient please comment politely and i will provide as much as i can.

Thank you.

Comment: Shared internet connections basically bridge the Pi to the internet, bypassing the host. I.e. without special configuration communication between the Pi and the host is not possible, and the configuration required (on the host) is not a Pi question. Why not just connect to your router.

Comment: do not have a router. or an ethernet port. my only access to the internet for the time (week or so) is through a cafe.